# What would you call a person who doubts his wife's character?

Tags: word-choice

A *cynic* or a *skeptic*? or something else?
I am trying to learn the differences between the two words.

Comment: Neither of those words would suit a man doubting his wife's character, IMO.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you have done some preliminary research; for example, what dictionaries have you consulted? Do the definitions they provide meet your need? A *cynic*, for example, would doubt *everyone*'s character, not just his wife's.

Comment: So are you looking for a word or trying to learn the difference between the two words you've listed?  These are entirely separate things.

Comment: _A wifecharacterdoubter_. Though I can't imagine having the need to.

Comment: The one flew over the cuckold's nest.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - why is it the woman's fault? What if he's just a paranoid wife-beater?

Comment: It's not the woman's fault. The man flew over his neighbouring cuckold's nest, which causes him to doubt. You need to read and comprehend the sentence properly.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the terms apply.
More context is needed to pick the proper term.  It depends on the presence of evidence.  If the doubt occurs with evidence present, a possible term is *suspicious.*  If the doubt occurs without evidence, a possible term is *paranoid.*

Comment: i meant it's in the person's nature to doubt for no reason, just like the attitude of a cynical person. As for the context, that even if his wife is not having any extra-marital affair but he still thinks that she does. (By the force of mere his doubting attitude) i.e. Shakespears Othello

Comment: @needhelp Suspicion without reason can be a symptom of *paranoia.*

Comment: If it's only his wife that he doubts then he is jealous, possessive, chauvinistic, insecure, as well as suspicious and paranoid. Cynicism and scepticism imply an attitude to the world in general and not just one's spouse.